# Access Denied denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: yes) after Ubuntu Upgrade to 20.04

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

I'm unable to access our system after upgrading our Ubuntu from 18.04 to 20.04. I'm getting `Access Denied  denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: yes)`. I tried using `mysql -u root -p` and after entering the password I can connect, but when using `mysql -u root -h 127.0.0.1` I'm getting the error `access denied`.

Just to add, there are 3 root users in the database as follow:

```
+------------------+-----------------+
| user             | host            |
+------------------+-----------------+
| remote           | %               |
| root             | 127.0.0.1       |
| root             | ::1             |
| debian-sys-maint | localhost       |
| mysql.session    | localhost       |
| mysql.sys        | localhost       |
| phpmyadmin       | localhost       |
| remote           | localhost       |
| root             | localhost       |
+------------------+-----------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'YOURPWD';
```